# Could Harry Potter have used the Resurrection Stone to resurrect good wizards so they could fight in the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

I believe that the Resurrection Stone has unlimited use, so it can be used multiple times. If so, Harry Potter would have had the option of using it to resurrect a good number of good wizards so they could fight in the Battle of Hogwarts, that is if these resurrected wizards would have agreed to do so.

I imagine that such an act would normally be forbidden in the wizarding world, but perhaps an exemption would have been made due to the dire need of saving the world from Lord Voldemort and his army.

Could Harry Potter have used the Resurrection Stone to resurrect good wizards so they could fight in the Battle of Hogwarts?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## They are likely not solid enough to fight.

When Harry uses the Resurrection Stone, the people it brings back are not truly restored to life, and are not particularly solid. They seem to have very little effect on the environment around them, since Harry only heard sounds that would be caused by slight movement made by frail bodies. Without the ability to affect the living world, those brought forth by the Resurrection Stone would be unable to fight.

> “He knew it had happened, because he heard slight movements around him that suggested frail bodies shifting their footing on the earthy, twig-strewn ground that marked the outer edge of the Forest. He opened his eyes and looked around.
>
> They were neither ghost nor truly flesh, he could see that. They resembled most closely the Riddle that had escaped from the diary, so long ago, and he had been memory made nearly solid. Less substantial than living bodies, but much more than ghosts, they moved towards him, and on each face there was the same loving smile.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 34 (The Forest Again)*</sup></sub>

Noncorporeal beings are very limited in their capabilities. Even a powerful wizard like Voldemort was unable to do much to help himself while bodiless.

> “Nevertheless, I was as powerless as the weakest creature alive, and without the means to help myself … for I had no body, and every spell which might have helped me required the use of a wand …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Those brought back by the Resurrection Stone are also limited in certain way to interaction only with the one who brought them back. Sirius tells Harry that they are a part of him, invisible to everyone else. This also means the possibility that they might exist solely for Harry as “part of him”, and not for anyone else.

> “They won’t be able to see you?’ asked Harry.
>
> ‘We are part of you,’ said Sirius. ‘Invisible to anyone else.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 34 (The Forest Again)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, since they are not solid and able to have much effect on the environment around them when Harry sees them, and the additional possibility of them only being real for Harry exists, it would not be very useful to use the Resurrection Stone to bring back people to fight because they would not be brought back in a way that they would be able to fight.

Comment: The resurrection stone is just some form of hallucinogenic drug, basically.

Comment: …and they have no wands.

Comment: At least they might be able to act as a spare pair of eyes. Scouts are good, invisible scouts are great, and scouts that don't exist for anyone but you are unstoppable.

Comment: This is a mixture between the Night Kind resurrecting half the North, and the ghost army in Lord of the Rings.

Answer (score 21):

### The resurrection stone can't actually bring anyone back from the dead.

When Harry uses the stone, his family that appears are ephemeral, closer to ghosts than anything living.  While it is unclear exactly how the stone works, it is highly unlikely that it can produce people capable of participating in a battle.

In fact, this was the moral of the 2nd Brother's fate in the fairy tale - he pined away because the stone did not restore his love to true life.

Comment: I also think it was strongly implied or outright stated that only the holder of the stone could see/interact with the apparitions, but I don't have my copy of the book to check for sure.  If anyone has quotes to back that up I'd be much obliged.

Comment: The quote you’re looking for is probably this: *“They won’t be able to see you?” asked Harry. “We are part of you,” said Sirius. “Invisible to anyone else.”* From Chapter 34.